# how to store appointments inside array without start and end time overlapping

Tags: javascript, overlapping

**problem statement**

i need to push new appointment inside this array but, i also **DONOT** want to overlap time of other already booked appointment

**my array**

Booked appointment contains previously added/booked appointments!

Allappointments= [
{
"startDay": 0,
"endDay": 7,
"Booked Appointments": [
{
"startTime": 1530,
"endTime": 1700
},
{
"startTime": 1030,
"endTime": 1300
}
]
}
];

**half solution**

i have managed to get this solution so far which which which works for start and end time,
But doesnt cover the start and end Day part,
day start with 0 and 7, covering whole week!

function validateTimeFrame(newTimeFrame, existingTimeFrames) {
const { startTime, endTime } = newTimeFrame;

```
    // Check for intersection with existing time frames
    const hasIntersection = existingTimeFrames.some((timeFrame) =>
      (startTime >= timeFrame.startTime && startTime <= timeFrame.endTime) ||
      (endTime >= timeFrame.startTime && endTime <= timeFrame.endTime)
    );
  
    // Check if it is encompassed by another time frame
    const isEncompassed = existingTimeFrames.some((timeFrame) =>
      startTime >= timeFrame.startTime && endTime <= timeFrame.endTime
    );
  
    // Check if it encompasses another time frame
    const encompasses = existingTimeFrames.some((timeFrame) =>
      startTime <= timeFrame.startTime && endTime >= timeFrame.endTime
    );
  
    return {
      hasIntersection,
      isEncompassed,
      encompasses
    };
  }
  
  // Example usage:
  const existingTimeFrames = [
    { startTime: 9, endTime: 10 },
    { startTime: 12, endTime: 14 },
    { startTime: 16, endTime: 18 }
  ];
  
  const newTimeFrame = { startTime: 11, endTime: 13 };
  
  const validationResult = validateTimeFrame(newTimeFrame, existingTimeFrames);
  console.log(validationResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

A day = 24 hours so it's enough to solve it just for hours.
Testing for overlap between 2 ranges is easily searchable in the web. So I constructed it into a written idea. First doing it for ranges of hours.

```js
function is_intersect(range1, range2) {
  var x1 = range1.startTime
  var x2 = range1.endTime
  var y1 = range2.startTime
  var y2 = range2.endTime
  return x1 <= y2 && y1 <= x2
}

function can_squeeze_in (range, ranges) {
  return !(ranges.find((item) => is_intersect(range, item)))
}

const existingTimeFrames = [
  { startTime: 9, endTime: 10 },
  { startTime: 12, endTime: 14 },
  { startTime: 16, endTime: 18 }
];
  
const newTimeFrame = { startTime: 11, endTime: 13 };
const willFit = {startTime: 19, endTime: 100}

console.log(can_squeeze_in(newTimeFrame, existingTimeFrames))
console.log(can_squeeze_in(willFit, existingTimeFrames))
```

Now if you have also `startDay` and `endDay` for each range, you can multiply them by 24 and add the `startTime` or `endTime` accordingly to reduce the problem.

```js
var range1 = {
  startDay: 2, startTime: 12,
  endDay: 3, endTime: 18
}


function normalize_range(range) {
  return {
    startTime: range.startDay * 24 + range.startTime,
    endTime: range.endDay * 24 + range.endTime,
  }
}


console.log(normalize_range(range1))
```